# Fast windows console printing

Tags: windows, performance, console, cmd

Windows console cmd.exe eat a lot of CPU during printing. When you print a lot of strings, it do it too slow in comparison to linux's xterm. Any suggestions of alternative for cmd.exe? Would be cool if the alternative can support bash language :)

Comment: Console window is not handled by cmd.exe. cmd.exe is the shell.

Comment: Typing War and Peace to the screen at a ten thousand lines a minute requires a GUI app.  The console host is a bit more in tune with human capabilities.  Just a bit, it is still a blur.  Write sane apps by dumping info that a human cannot or would want to read to a log file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want bash and a decent terminal to accompany it on Windows, with some system integration, then [mintty](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/) on [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) is your best bet. (mintty is installable from within the Cygwin setup program.)

Note, however, that most console-mode Windows programs are not compatible enough with *nix-style terminals to work interactively inside mintty.